# Wait for BAPI to complete: is STARTING NEW TASK an option?

Tags: abap

I'm dealing with a pretty common issue. Consider the code:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CREATE_SOMETHING' ... .
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
    EXPORTNG WAIT = 'X'.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CHANGE_SOMETHING' ... .
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
    EXPORTNG WAIT = 'X'.
```

Here I use BAPIs to create some object and make some changes in it right after the creation. The problem is that when `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` returns, the object may still be locked for some time, so `BAPI_CHANGE_SOMETHING` will fail.

The most recommended option I've seen so far is putting a loop right after the 1st commit that will check if the object is locked (`WAIT UP TO ... SECONDS` together with `SELECT`/`ENQUEUE`).

There is one more suggestion, however: wrap the object creation code into a FM and call it with a `STARTING NEW TASK` addition. So, the whole thing would look like this:

```
FUNCTION 'Z_CREATE_SMTH'.
    CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CREATE_SOMETHING' ... .
    CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
        EXPORTNG WAIT = 'X'.
ENDFUNCTION.

...

CALL FUNCTION 'Z_CREATE_SMTH' STARTING NEW TASK 'TSK' DESTINATION 'NONE'
    PERFORMING on_done ON END OF TASK.

WAIT UNITL lv_done = abap_true.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CHANGE_SOMETHING' ... .
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
    EXPORTNG WAIT = 'X'.

...

FORM on_done USING p_task.
    lv_done = abap_true.
    ...
ENDFORM.
```

The main point is that when async function call completes, it's guaranteed that all changes are committed and and all locks are released. However, I haven't found any proofs for that yet, so my question is: does this make sense, or `WAIT` + `ENQUEUE` is the most recommended option?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL` as well.

Comment: So, I just run `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL`, wrap all my updates into FMs and call those FMs via `CALL FUNCTION ... IN UPDATE TASK`? And that is it? This looks pretty simple, why do people bother with loops and `WAITs`?

Comment: If it were that simple, I would have made an answer out of it. Sadly, it isn't. I just wanted to make sure you knew about this as well.

Comment: OK, as far as I understand the problem, normally BAPI updates run in a separate process (update task), which may be out of syn with my program work process. I.e., when `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` returns, that does not guratantee that all changes have allready been committed to the DB. With `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL` all updates are performed in the program work process, so there should be no sync issues. What's the catch?